# Absolute URL in Django template

Tags: django, templates

I'm just started using Django so my quetion might be stupid :)

I have an URL to a different site in my model(TextField, "othersite.com"). I'm trying to display it in the template like that `<a href="{{ article.url }}" >`
But tricky Django gives me `<a href="http://mysite.com/articles/othersite.com" >`

1. What do I do to get `<a href="othersite.com" >` ?
2. Sorry for my language, if it has any mistakes :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your browser is entering the additional text, instead of Django. This happens in the absence of a complete URL to avoid unexpected behavior.

You can work around the issue by fixing your data, or by modifying your template like this:

```
<a href="http://{{ article.url }}" >
```

Answer (score 0):

If all urls need to be absolute, this could be resolved by using a custom template tag and filter.

```
@register.filter
@stringfilter
def absoluteurl(url):
    if "http" not in url:
        return 'http://%s' % url
    else:
        return url
```

Then you can simply `<a href="{{ article.url|absoluteurl }}" >`

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/custom-template-tags/